How long can I keep homemade concentrated meat broth?
I made a broth from a pork leg (bones and meat, already broiled), also adding some browned veg and herbs. Then I reduced the broth by about tenfold and put it in a jar. After cooling the result was a stiff jelly.
This came about because I had received two broiled legs but got fed up after eating up the first by and by; and wanted to conserve fridge space. The end product turned out to be delicious on bread in its own right, with its added Maillard notes from reducing, like on cream cheese or founding a tomato sandwich. But it did take a while to finish those 150ml of jelly, ten days perhaps. Now I wonder if I was living fast there.
How long may I officially keep such meat broth jelly around once opened? Also, I suppose the sealed, unfrozen keeping time will be lower than for liquid broth due to low water activity -- how low?
I have seen these similar questions. The differences are that I'm mainly asking about time to use up once opened, and that there explicitly are veggies in the mix if that matters.

@dandavis Fat is entirely different to broth. The water activity in fat will be low (fats and water are immiscible) so fewer things can grow, but in broth will be high so lots could grow.

@bob1, but what if most water was driven off leaving gelatin and solids? Doesn't low water activity actually favor botulinum?

@ariola low water activity means that things can't grow as there isn't enough water available. Gelatin gels are still mostly water; a 6% solution of gelatin is a very rubbery substance once set, but still has high water activity at 94% water. See the table here and look at the dry milk powder value for some idea.

I don't see why your broth gelatin would last any longer than anything else in the fridge, which has already been answered, however maybe there are aspects of this I haven't considered. You could pour it in ice cube trays and avoid the issue, which would be my suggestion.

@GdD That would be from 2 to 14 days depending on the item. Do you mean like straight broth? And ice cubes on toast don't sound like a hit ;)

You just melt them on demand @ariola. If you freeze them into cubes you take them out the evening before you want them and put them in the fridge, if you freeze it quickly you would have a week to use each one.

We have many "how long can I keep..." questions and answers.
